# Bring back mobile version of website in WebBrowser control for wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

Is it possible to bring back web pages in a mobile format, if available, before showing the normal rendering of a web page? I noticed I was getting both when I used it. Or is this enabled by default?

EDIT: For example in ie on the phone you can request to recieve webpages in a mobile version or desktop version. Is this option available to developers and if not what is the default for the control?

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on your question - e.g. with an example url and with a bit more about what you mean about "getting both" - thanks

Comment: For example in ie on the phone you can request to recieve webpages in a mobile version or desktop version. Is this option available to developers and if not what is the default for the control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there's no API for toggling this setting - and no easy way to intercept the outgoing HTTP calls from the browser control.

Looking at some output from the emulator it looks like the mobile/full setting toggles this in the User-Agent:

> Mobile -
>   Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+Phone+OS+7.0;+Trident/3.1;+IEMobile/7.0;+Microsoft;+XDeviceEmulator)
>
> Desktop -
>   Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+XBLWP7;+ZuneWP7)

Here also are some mobile agents captured "in the wild" - http://www.elucidsoft.com/blog/2010/11/19/windows-phone-7-user-agents/

It looks like this settings is a global setting for the OS - so whatever the user chooses in the browser settings is also used in your app (I think this is what I just saw).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem for a very, very long time and I finally figured it out with the following:

> string header =
>   "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U;
>   CPU iPhone OS 4_1 like Mac OS X;
>   en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8B117
>   Safari/6531.22.7";
>
> MyWebBrowser.Navigate(new
>   Uri("http://www.google.com"), null,
>   header);

The following header DID NOT work for me (on the gmail website):

Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+Phone+OS+7.0;+Trident/3.1;+IEMobile/7.0;+Microsoft;+XDeviceEmulator)

Answer (score 1):

The `WebBrowser` control does not expose an API that enables you to choose between the Desktop or the Mobile version of a web page. You could use Fiddler to trap the traffic for outgoing requests (from the [emulator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/10/15/fiddler-and-the-windows-phone-emulator.aspx) or a [device](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/01/09/debugging-windows-phone-7-device-traffic-with-fiddler.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)) to see if there's anything in particular about the request that you might be able to replicate in yoru own requests.

Comment: Agree with Derek. But is the question about being able to see Mobile versions of websites on the WebBrowser control? I believe it uses the same shell as IE on the phone; but just has configurability toned down. So, if the website is sniffing requests from a web browser, it should get the same from the Meta tags of the request from IE & the WebBrowser control. It may then be up to the site to render accordingly.